# How to achieve s3 server side encryption, when using s3 with AWS SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

We have a use case where we have to manage SQS messages using S3 as described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-s3-messages.html). In this case how do we implement Server Side encryption(SSE) of messages sent to S3?. In the page it says to create an AmazonS3Client and use it to create AmazonSQSExtendedClient. But I don't see any option where we can specify that we need messages in S3 to be encrypted using  SSE.

This [link](http://aws.myutils.site/html/devtools.html) talks about encryption of SQS message payloads in S3 using S3 Client encryption. But is it possible to achieve Server Side Encryption of SQS message payloads in S3 ?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-server-side-encryption-for-amazon-simple-queue-service-sqs/

Comment: I tried this. If I enable SSE in SQS, and use SQSExtendedClient to store the payloads in S3, it does not encrypt the messages in S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently AmazonSQSExtendedClient does not support S3 server side encryption.

Have a look at the Extended Client [Source Code](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sqs-java-extended-client-lib/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazon/sqs/javamessaging/AmazonSQSExtendedClient.java). In the code the method constructing S3 put object request,

```
private void storeTextInS3(String s3Key, String messageContentStr, Long messageContentSize) {
        InputStream messageContentStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(messageContentStr.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        ObjectMetadata messageContentStreamMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        messageContentStreamMetadata.setContentLength(messageContentSize);
        PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(clientConfiguration.getS3BucketName(), s3Key,
                messageContentStream, messageContentStreamMetadata);
        try {
            clientConfiguration.getAmazonS3Client().putObject(putObjectRequest);
        } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
            String errorMessage = "Failed to store the message content in an S3 object. SQS message was not sent.";
            LOG.error(errorMessage, e);
            throw new AmazonServiceException(errorMessage, e);
        } catch (AmazonClientException e) {
            String errorMessage = "Failed to store the message content in an S3 object. SQS message was not sent.";
            LOG.error(errorMessage, e);
            throw new AmazonClientException(errorMessage, e);
        }
    }
```

It does not include the extension for setting server side encryption. If you plan to modify the source code of the extended client, you can include server side encryption support as shown below.

```
PutObjectRequest putRequest = new PutObjectRequest(
                                      bucketName, keyName, file);

// Request server-side encryption.
ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
objectMetadata.setSSEAlgorithm(ObjectMetadata.AES_256_SERVER_SIDE_ENCRYPTION);     
putRequest.setMetadata(objectMetadata);
```

For more details of S3 server side encryption using Java SDK have a look at [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/SSEUsingJavaSDK.html) link.